# How can I use specific outgoing IP for fsockopen in PHP?

Tags: php, ip

I should use IP from

gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']);

In *fsockopen* as outgoing.

I have a construction like this:

```
if ($this->sock = fsockopen($host, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, (float) $timeout)) {}
```

Is there a way to do so without changing whole code?
If no, please advise to me the shortest way to do so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specify source ip using fsockopen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765269/specify-source-ip-using-fsockopen)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `fsockopen()`, which is a wrapper around several networking calls, use `socket(...)` to create a socket, `bind(...)` it to a specific local IP address (and random port), and then `connect(...)` from there to your destination.

You'll likely have to massage your variables into the specific parameters those system calls require.

Oh, this is already answered here:
[Specify source ip using fsockopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765269/specify-source-ip-using-fsockopen)