# Outgoing IP address for PHP stream_socket_client() and fsockopen()

Tags: php, smtp, ip

The library `PHPMailer` uses the functions `stream_socket_client()` and `fsockopen()` to connect to an SMTP server.

My server is using IPv4 and IPv6, and (in additional to a single stable IPv6 address) it defines multiple IPv6 addresses on each reboot.

The SMTP server is quite restrictive, and expects the requests to come from a single, specific IPv6 asdress. **How do I tell PHP which IP address to use for outgoing connections?**

I already found the `CURLOPT_DNS_INTERFACE` [option for cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), but nothing that refers to the above mentioned functions.

Comment: As I do not like to rewrite PHPMailer, the option to use bind() instead also seems not useful for my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473391/how-can-i-use-specific-outgoing-ip-for-fsockopen-in-php